# Starting .jar file from C# - .properties file not found

Tags: java, c#, log4j, docx4j

I've been developing a webservice in C# where I have to convert Word docx files to PDF. After searching for a long time I settled on docx4j, a java library, to make the conversion. The .jar file works as expected when I run it from a command line, but when I start it from my C# code through System.Diagnostics.Process I get the following errors:

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.docx4j.jaxb.Context).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
```

...

```
WARN org.docx4j.utils.ResourceUtils .getResource line 84 - Couldn't get resource: docx4j.properties
WARN org.docx4j.Docx4jProperties .init line 22 - Couldn't find/read docx4j.properties; docx4j.properties not found via classloader.
```

The C# code making the call looks like this:

```
        Process javaCall = new Process();

        var dir = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~");

        ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
        startInfo.Arguments = "-Xmx2048m -jar \"" + dir + "\\App_Data\\DocxToPDF.jar\" \"" + sourcePath + "\"";
        startInfo.FileName = "\"" + System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["JdkFilePath"] + "\"";
        startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;

        javaCall.StartInfo = startInfo;
        javaCall.Start();

        javaCall.WaitForExit();
```

I've checked the windows security settings on the .jar file and the directory it's in and both are set to full permissions to all users. I don't understand why I get different results from making a manual command line call and one from System.Diagnostics.Process.

I'd really appreciate some help and will provide more info if you need it.

Comment: Opening Java from C# to convert a word doc into a PDF? This cannot be the best solution

Comment: @ControlAltDel, My first idea was using the Word.Interop libraries, but since my code is supposed to run on a server that was out of the question. My options were to pay up for a license for Aspose, install LibreOffice on the server and use their solution or use this open source java library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, so that answer turned out to be easier than I expected. By moving the .properties to the same folder as the .jar file instead of them being nested inside the program managed to find them...

I guess I should try the easy fixes first next time, thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set environment variable Path of java.exe executable or specify the full path of java.exe.

ProcessStartInfo ps = new ProcessStartInfo(@"c:\Program Files\java\jdk1.7.0\bin\java.exe",@"-jar C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\myJarFile.jar");
 Process.Start(ps);

By default   command line knows java  path   but ProcessStartInfodoes not know where is java

Comment: I specify the file path to my java.exe at the fifth row of C# code above, at 
startInfo.FileName = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["JdkFilePath"]